# ASP.Net MVC returning value from ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a grid of Payees... Simple grid with a few columns. My view has the following:

```
<table width="600" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

Payee Name
    Used
    Future Payments set
    No. Transactions

<% foreach (var p in Model.PayeeListeItems)
   {%>
   
    
    <%=Html.ActionLink("Modify", "Modify", p.PayeeId) %>
    
    <%=p.Name %>
    <%=p.IsUsed.ToString() %>
    <%=p.IsAssignedToBill.ToString() %>
    <%=p.TransactionCount.ToString() %>

<%
   }%>

It's the ActionLink I am battling with. I have a Modify method in my Controller, but I'm not sure how to get the PayeeId I am trying to pass, which is the selected Payee...

When I click the link at runtime, I get:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Modify(Int32)' An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

My controller method looks like this:

```
        public ActionResult Modify(Int32 id)
    {
        PayeeDto p = Services.PayeeServices.GetPayeeById(id);
        SinglePayeeItem spi = new SinglePayeeItem
                                  {
                                      Deleted = p.Deleted,
                                      Name = p.Name,
                                      PayeeId = p.PayeeId
                                  };
        return View(spi);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using p.payeeId as the RouteValues parameter, right? You need to pass it in as an object. So your ActionLink would look something like:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Modify", "Modify", new { id = p.PayeeId })
```